# Is there a way to get a count of non-empty rows with an Office Script?

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, power-automate, office-scripts

I have an office script that only affects the first 3 rows of a column and I would like to make it work for every non-blank row in only the first column. Every time this script is run, the amount of rows in the workbook will vary so I want to learn how to make it dynamic. There will not be empty rows between data, so the first empty row should signify the end of the document. There also will only be data in the first column before the script is run.

Excel's "Record actions" button gave me this script when I performed my required edits on 3 rows of data to give Excel an example of what I need to do. Each row of column A will have data that looks like the following inline code `columnA,columnB,columnC` and the below script separates data exactly as I need into each respectable column, but only on the first 3 rows. I believe the solution for this problem lies in changing `getRange("A1:A3")` on lines 4 and 5 into something that gets the range of all non-empty cells in column A but I'm not sure what the method would be for this.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Text to columns on range A1:A3 on selectedSheet
    for (let row = 0; row < selectedSheet.getRange("A1:A3").getRowCount() ; row++) {
        let sourceRange = selectedSheet.getRange("A1:A3");
        let destinationRange = selectedSheet.getRange("A1");
        let sourceRangeValues = sourceRange.getRow(row).getValues()[0][0].toString().split(/[,]/)
        destinationRange.getOffsetRange(row, 0).getResizedRange(0, sourceRangeValues.length - 1).setValues([sourceRangeValues]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Option 1: Get the dynamic range with `getUsedRange`.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let usedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
  if (usedRange) {
    let sourceRange = usedRange.getColumn(0);
    let rowCount = sourceRange.getRowCount();
    let dataValues = sourceRange.getValues()
    for (let row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
      let splitValues = dataValues[row][0].toString().split(/[,]/)
      sourceRange.getCell(row, 0).getResizedRange(0, splitValues.length - 1).setValues([splitValues]);
    }
  }
  else {
    console.log('No data on worksheet')
  }
}
```

> Option 2: Loop through cells in column A and stop at a blank cell

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let rowCnt = 0;
  while(true) {
    let cellValue = selectedSheet.getCell(rowCnt,0).getValue().toString();
    if (cellValue.length === 0) {  
      break
    }
    else {
      let splitValues = cellValue.split(/[,]/)
      selectedSheet.getCell(rowCnt++, 0).getResizedRange(0, splitValues.length - 1).setValues([splitValues]);
    }
  }
}
```